# Why does the one paragraph solution to IMO Problem 6 1988 work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, contest-math, solution-verification

Emanouil Atanassov, famously said to have completed the "hardest" IMO problem in a single paragraph and went on to receive the special prize, [gave the proof quoted below,](http://dynamicmathematicslearning.com/appendix-MKSiu-IMO2016.pdf)

> Question: Let a and b be positive integers such that $ab+1$ divides $a^2+b^2$ Show that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is the square of an integer

> Proof: $k=\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1} \implies a^2-kab+b^2=k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ Assume $k$ is not a perfect square. Note that for any integral solution $(a,b)$ we have $a>0, b>0$ since k is not a perfect square. Let $(a,b)$ be an integral solution with $a>0, b>0$ and $a+b$ minimum. We shall produce from it another integral solution $(a',b)$ with $a'>0 , \ b>0$ and $a'+b<a+b$. Contradiction (We omit the argument for arriving at $(a',b)$)

$a'=0$ is sufficient for $k$ being a square, but it is not true in general. This proof seems to imply $a'=0$ for all solutions $(a,b)$. The only assumption contradicted is the minimality of $a+b$, not the assumption $k$ is not a perfect square. How does the assertion trivially follow from this proof?

EDIT:
Here is the proof modified, but without the assumption $k$ is not a perfect square.

> $k=\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1} \implies a^2-kab+b^2=k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ Let $(a,b)$ be an integral solution with $a>0, b>0$ and $a+b$ minimum. We shall produce from it another integral solution $(a',b)$ with $a'>0 , \ b>0$ and $a'+b<a+b$. Contradiction (We omit the argument for arriving at $(a',b)$)

I have also removed the second sentence, because $a,b>0$ is given in the question. What does this proof imply that the first does not?

Comment: "Let $S_k$ be the set of tuples $(a,b)$ for which $a^2-kab+b^2=k$ where $k$ is not a perfect square. $a>0, b>0$ implies there is some elements in $S_k$ for which $a+b$ reaches the minimum for $S_k$. But then we find a pair with lower $a'+b$ in the same $S_k$ given $a+b$ is already the minimum. The only chance is left that $S_k$ is empty" -- like this.

Comment: A simple [contradiction proof](https://youtu.be/usEQRx4J_ew)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin This argument can be made without assuming $k$ is not a perfect square. Though it is unclear to me why, I can only conclude you cannot assume $a+b$ is minimum.

Comment: The most interesting step ($(a,b)\to (a',b)$ is left out (for it maybe we may need k not being a perfect square). $S_k$ is countable, $a$ and $b$ both integers $>0$, you can't _take_ minimum of $a+b$ only if $S_k$ is empty. Are you familiar with $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ proof? Let $\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then we prove $2|\gcd(a,b)$. -- It's the same kind of argument.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping, it contains the example from OP.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin In Euclid's sqrt(2) proof, the one assumption clearly leads to a contradiction. In this proof, there are two assumptions. We see $a+b$ minimum gets contradicted. I do not see how this is implied by $k$ is a perfect square$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Could you take a look at my answer?

Answer (score 5):

1. If there are solutions $(a,b)$ for which $k$ is not a perfect square, then $a,b>0$.
2. Also, if there are solutions $(a,b)$ for which $k$ is not a perfect square, then there will be, among those solutions, one for which $a+b$ is minimal.
3. Then the author finds another solution $(a',b)$ with $a'<a$, which implies that $a'+b<a+b$.
4. But that's impossible, since we were assuming that $(a,b)$ was the solution for which $a+b$ takes the smallest value.

Comment: None of this is wrong, but what does it have to do with $k$ being a square? (1) is given in the question. $a'=2.4$ could be the new root, but since it is not an integer, it does not contradict minimality of $(a,b)$. (You can prove that it does obey the restrictions of a,b , but this is not seen in the solution). I would really like to see how this solution shows the minimality of $a+b$ is contradicted if and only if $k$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: No, $a'$ could no possibly be equal to $2.4$, since $2.4$ is not a positive integer. And if $k$ is a perfect square, then $a$ might be $0$ and thereferore there would not be a non-negative integer $a'$ such that $a'<a$.

Comment: $a'$ can be proven to be a positive integer, but from what has been written in the solution, there is nothing that suggests it must. However, we can favourably assume this has been omitted.  $a$ cannot equal 0 it is a positive integer. There exist many solutions $a,b$ where $a'=0$ but there are also solutions where $a'\neq 0$ , take $a=30, b=8, k=4$. Does this proof aim to show $k \neq n^2 \implies a'=0$, because otherwise the assumed minimality is contradicted?

Comment: The proof aims at proving that if $(a,b)$ is a solution with $a,b>0$, then there is another solution $(a',b)$ such that $a'<a$, which implies that $a'+b<a+b$. Since I do not know how $a'$ is defined, there is no much more that I can say here. Perhaps that the definition of $a'$ uses the fact that $k$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: It does. See the Vieta jumping wiki link in the question's comments, $a'$ denoted $x_2$ there.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you.

Comment: We don't have the definition, but I think we both know how we get there with vieta formulae. I would strongly hope that proof-critical statements in the proof were not omitted. I cannot see how we both are not on the same page here unless I'm really missing something. How does $k$ being square lead to this contradiction? We should be able to assume minimality, but somehow we land a contradiction from what purely seems like rearranging a quadratic to me.

Comment: Your first comment to my answer begins with the words “None of this is wrong”. If so, then what prevents you from accepting that this really proves what it is supposed to prove?

Comment: I don't disagree with anything in your answer, that does not mean that it proves it, you just listed true statements. These statements do not imply $k$ must be a perfect square.

Comment: Yes they do, since that argument assumes that $k$ is *not* a perfect square. So, since we get a contradiction whenever $k$ is not a perfect square, there can be a solution only when $k$ *is* a perfect square.

Comment: No, the assumption must be directly imply the contradiction. This becomes easy to misinterpret when there are multiple assumptions. Otherwise, I could write at the top of the proof, Assume 1=1, then conclude at the end $1\neq1$,

Answer (score 2):

Full solution verbatim from [en.wiki/Vieta jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping):

#### Standard Vieta jumping

The concept of standard Vieta jumping is a proof by contradiction, and consists of the following three steps:[${}^{[1]}$](http://georgmohr.dk/tr/tr09taltvieta.pdf)

1. Assume toward a contradiction that some solution exists that violates the given requirements.
2. Take the minimal such solution according to some definition of minimality.
3. Show that this implies the existence of a smaller solution, hence a contradiction.

#### Example

Problem #6 at IMO 1988: Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$.  Prove that $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1}$ is a perfect square.[${}^{[2]}$](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=352683)[${}^{[3]}$](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath334.htm)

1. Fix some value $k$ that is a non-square positive integer. Assume there exist positive integers $(a, b)$ for which $k = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1}$.
2. Let $(A, B)$ be positive integers for which $k = \frac{A^2 + B^2}{AB + 1}$ and such that $A + B$ is minimized, and without loss of generality assume $A \ge B$.
3. Fixing $B$, replace $A$ with the variable $x$ to yield $x^2 – (kB)x + (B^2 – k) = 0$.  We know that one root of this equation is $x_1 = A$. By standard properties of quadratic equations, we know that the other root satisfies $x_2 = kB – A$ and $x_2 = \frac{B^2 – k}{A}$.
4. The first expression for $x_2$ shows that $x_2$ is an integer, while the second expression implies that $x_2 \ne 0$ since $k$ is not a perfect square. From $\frac{x_2^2 + B^2}{x_2B + 1} = k > 0$ it further follows that $x_2$ is a positive integer. Finally, $ A \ge B$ implies that $x_2 = \frac{B^2 − k}{A} < A$ and thus $x_2 + B < A + B$, which contradicts the minimality of $A + B$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it figured out and will allude to the Wikipedia proof given in Alexey's answer as the arguments are the same and I believe me source has been unreliable in "omitting" steps.

The minimality of $A+B$ is contradicted. (2) and (3) are irrelevant to $k$. (4) says $x$ cannot be $0$ if $k$ is not a perfect square. So $x\neq 0$. But if $x\neq 0$, purely through algebra, independent of $k$ being square or not, we contradict minimality. So, the crux, $(A,B)$ minimises $A+B$. only if $x_2=0$. Since there is no minimum of $(A,B)$ pairs when $k$ is not a square, we can conclude there are no such pairs.

Whether or not Atanassov found this so trivial that he kept this in his head remains a mystery.